# Drawing a Diagram

Tags: c

I'm stuck understanding a problem i have and i would appreciate your help.
I'm very new to C so please bear with me.

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int h(int value){
    if (value % 2 == 0){
    // (***)
    printf("Even");}
    return 0;
}

void g(double value){
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<value; i++){
        printf("%d", i);
    }
    h(value);
}


int f(int value){
    static int sum;
    sum += value;
    printf("%d", sum + value);
    g(sum);
    return 0;
}

int main(){
   int *p,
   double *q;
   p = (int *)malloc(10*sizeof(int));
   q = (double *)malloc(10*sizeof(double));
   f(1);
   f(2);
   f(3);
}
```

and i know how to find the output but now i'm being asked to draw how the memory looks at the place `(***)` in function `h()`. suppose that the stack  starts at the address 100 and the length of return address is 4 bytes . i need to write on the stack the length of each cell containing a memory.

Can anyone teach me how to do this?

Comment: See http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~chang/cs313.s02/stack.shtml for a description of what happens in a C function call.

Comment: How the memory looks depends entirely on compiler choices outside the programmer's control, or indeed consideration.

Comment: Also **Don't cast the result of malloc() in C**. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc